# Google AdEx Seller API doesn't support Service accounts

Tags: google-oauth, google-api-python-client, google-reseller-api

I want to pull periodic reports via [Google Seller API](https://developers.google.com/ad-exchange/seller-rest/). Is there a way, to login into Seller account without having to go via regular OAuth redirection ?

Comment: Do you have access to the account in question?  If so create a service account to access it.  If not and the account belongs to a user then you need to use Oauth2

Comment: @DaImTo: Apparently the API doesn't support Service accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would make no sense to try to use a service account to access AdEx, which is owned by a user account. You need to obtain a refresh token for the user account, store it somewhere, then use it to obtain an access token whenever you need to access the API. This answer gives the steps to follow [How do I authorise an app (web or installed) without user intervention? (canonical ?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766912/how-do-i-authorise-an-app-web-or-installed-without-user-intervention-canonic)